Draw repeated random samples while repeating structure, e.g. in `rep` (or mimic this behaviour)
I want to draw repeated random samples dynamically based on some variable n_times
E.g.:
n_times <- 2
rep(
  x = rnorm(3),
  times = n_times
)
#> [1] -0.06282421  0.57893598 -0.40280464 -0.06282421  0.57893598 -0.40280464

Here rep is drawing the sample first, then repeating it. I'd like to draw a new sample each time it is repeated.
In this extremely simple example, I could just stuff n_times into rnorm to get different samples:
n_times <- 2
rnorm(n_times * 3)
#> [1]  1.01661877 -1.70475732 -0.01316538 -0.07078134  0.81297461 -0.33472840

However I want to repeat a more complex series of different samples within a list, and doing this dynamically seems more complex, e.g.:
n_times <- 2
rep(
  x = list(
    a = rnorm(1),
    b = rlnorm(3),
    d = matrix(
      data = runif(4),
      nrow = 2
    )
  ),
  times = n_times
)

#> $a
#> [1] 0.8858115
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1.439997 1.455555 4.146259
#> 
#> $d
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.6682130 0.9883577
#> [2,] 0.7576468 0.7300474
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 0.8858115
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1.439997 1.455555 4.146259
#> 
#> $d
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.6682130 0.9883577
#> [2,] 0.7576468 0.7300474

Ideally, each iteration of a, b, and d would contain new samples.
While it would be easy enough to dynamically create the correct number of samples outside of rep, it's creating a list dynamically and fitting them in that I can't get my head around. Adding via loop seems possible but very awkward.
Created on 2024-10-01 with reprex v2.1.0

If you're not looking to change the parameters of the functions within the list, you can use replicate(), otherwise you can use Map().

OK great so with thanks to @Iroha's comment, I can achieve desired behaviour with replicate:
n_times <- 2
internal_fun <- function(){
  list(
    a = rnorm(1),
    b = rlnorm(3),
    d = matrix(
      data = runif(4),
      nrow = 2
    )
  )
}

replicate(
  n = n_times,
  expr = internal_fun(),
  simplify = FALSE
)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] -0.6850743
#> 
#> [[1]]$b
#> [1] 1.9247365 1.4571854 0.7393512
#> 
#> [[1]]$d
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.0165695 0.4036282
#> [2,] 0.1592526 0.5828538
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$a
#> [1] 2.087253
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] 2.502234 6.440260 3.318749
#> 
#> [[2]]$d
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.7871132 0.6730501
#> [2,] 0.4739253 0.3097537

Created on 2024-10-01 with reprex v2.1.0
